# sass change icon of searchbar ionic 3

Tags: sass, ionic3, searchbar

I would like to change the icon of the `ion-searchbar` to an `add icon` or a custom image.
In the .scss file I've tried:

```
.searchbar-search-icon{
    background-image: "http://i.imgur.com/ATn5jLZ.png"
}
```

but the icon doesn't change. This is the html code for searchbar:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Add tag ... "></ion-searchbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
.searchbar-search-icon {
     background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/ATn5jLZ.png') !important;
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.searchbar-search-icon{
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/ATn5jLZ.png");
}
```